# ObjectController and ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I am learning [*emberjs*](http://emberjs.com/) form [trek.github.com](http://trek.github.com). That tutorial used both `Em.ObjectController` and `Em.ArrayController`. And There is also `Em.Controller`.

I am confused when to use them, I guess `Em.ObjectController` is for single object, `Em.ArrayController` is for array and `Em.Controller` is just for ApplicationController.

Is there any blessed rule for when to use which?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually, if your Controller represent a list of items, you would use the `Ember.ArrayController`, and if the controller represents a single item, you would use the `Ember.ObjectController`. Something like the following:

```
MyApp.ContactsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: [],
    selectedContact: null
});

MyApp.SelectedContactController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    contentBinding: 'contactsController.selectedContact',
    contactsController: null
});
```

Then in your `Ember.Router` (if you use them), you would connect the two inside the `connectOutlets` function:

```
connectOutlets: function(router) {
    router.get('selectedContactController').connectControllers('contacts');
}
```

Edit: I have never used the `Ember.Controller`. Looking at the source code, it seems like you might want to use this if you are building a custom controller that doesn't fit in with the two other controllers.

Comment: My understanding is that you use `Ember.Controller` when the controller is a not a proxy (neither for an object nor for an array) like in the case of your `App.ApplicationController`.

Comment: Joachim pauldechov Thanks for your precise reply! Now I know the difference of them.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is that it depends on model from route.

**If model is an array then you should use ArrayController.** It will allow you to implement in easy way sorting or filtering in future. ArrayController is connecting usually ObjectControllers.

**When your model is an instance of Ember Object then you should use ObjectController.** It takes place when you are using for instance ember data. With Objectcontroller you can access model properties directly. You don't have to write `model.property` each time.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.Object.create({name: 'Mathew'});
    }
});

My name is {{name}}
```

**Finally, when one doesn't have model there is an ideal situation to use just `Ember.Controller`**. It is not going to allow direct access to model properties as ObjectController.